# Video-inverting my bash prompt

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

This is my **prompt**, as specified in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

...that yields something like:

[image: Prompt usual color]

I would like to **video-invert** the colors of the `luis@PortatilAsu` part.
I have read on the net that the *ANSI Code* prefix for video inversion on any text string should be `\033[7m`, so I tested:

```
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\[\033[7m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

(note the extra `\033[7m` and its position).
And the results seem to be fine:

[image: Inverted prompt]

But the prompt config seems rather awkward, and some docs say you can screw things if you don't put codes in the right place and have strange behaviors like cursor not steping, backspace going over the prompt itself, new lines not happening... etc.

Is the **position** I have choosen for the PS1 prompt variable all right?
My prompt seems to be working OK right now (no problem with backspaces, line endings... etc); should it manifest such strange behaviors?
Any **basic rule** (if it exists) to prevent that "strange behavior" of the prompt would be great, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine, but you can just put your `7` inside previous colour definition, and additionally I would remove all unnecessary zeros, so:

```
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;7;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]:\[\033[1;34m\]\w\[\033[0m\]\$ "
```

Comment: OK, upon your optimization, I think I understand the syntax now. Thanks you but, why not removing the zeros in '033' too?

Comment: Because `\033[` is not colour code, it is escape code which is interpreted by bash as "from now on till `m` all numbers will be interpreted as colour codes separated by `;`".

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez A leading zero is part of the conventional syntax for denoting octal notation, and octal is what is required here. `033` is 27 in decimal (3 * 8 + 3), not 33.